# Comment on dit « Partner in crime » en français?

Tags: expressions

Est-ce qu'il y a une expression en français comme « Partner in crime » ?

Comment: Merci d'expliquer l'usage de l'expression anglaise dans la question.

Comment: Tout simplement « complice ».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Complices dans le crime* ([Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/partner/600561)). Cela dit, on ne peut pas vraiment parler d'une expression consacrée, même si elle semble parfaitement correcte — rien chez *Le Grand Robert* (2005), par ex.

**Édition :** la réponse d'Iside m'évoque aussi les « larrons » bibliques, et de là les “larrons en foire” — d'après le *Grand Robert*:

> S'entendre comme larrons en foire, à merveille, **comme des voleurs qui
>   sont de connivence pour monter un coup.**

Comment: Je dirait juste *complice*. C'est suffisant en l’occurrence. Utiliser *crime* ici impliquerait un crime réel (alors que *partner in crime* est généralement métaphorique).

Answer (score 6):

Je pense que l'on dit "complice"

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/complice

Answer (score 4):

"Des acolytes" traduit bien l'expression "Partners in crime".

Comment: J'aime bien **acolytes**, oui, qui est souvent employé en ce sens. On a aussi **compères** ou **comparses** dans certains contextes plus littéraires que judiciaires.

Comment: Pas vraiment, non. Un acolyte est toujours un inférieur alors que *partner* est neutre de ce point de vue. Et on peut parler d'acolyte même si le but n'est pas néfaste, alors que *partner in crime* est soit à but néfaste soit utilisé ironiquement.

Comment: Un acolyte n'est pas toujours un inférieur mais toujours un complice. Pour le reste tout dépend du contexte, de l'intention de celui qui parle ou qui écrit. "Partners in crime" est souvent utilisé de façon taquine ou ironique. We will have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring “généraux,” this Ngram using “[Hitler et ses *](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Hitler%20et%20ses%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2CHitler%20et%20ses%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9raux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20collaborateurs%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20lieutenants%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20acolytes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20amis%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20complices%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20conseillers%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20partisans%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20alli%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20bandes%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2CHitler%20et%20ses%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9raux%3B%2Cc1%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20collaborateurs%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20lieutenants%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20acolytes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20amis%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20complices%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20conseillers%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20partisans%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20alli%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHitler%20et%20ses%20bandes%3B%2Cc0) ” puts “[collaborateurs](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/collaborateur)” right behind “Iside’s answer (acolytes) and just ahead of the other answers (complices).

Although the “to cooperate treacherously” sense of collaborate is used in French primarily to refer to the “collabos” of “39-45,” even without its “treacherous” notion, [collaborateur/trice](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/collaborateur_collaboratrice/17136) could still capture at least the metaphoric sense of “partner in crime.”